# MySQL select rows where other 3 rows exist

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables

entities

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
| 4  | store_1 |
+----+---------+
```

published

```
+----+-------------+
| id | status      |
+----+-------------+
| 4  | sold        |
| 4  | bought      |
| 4  | transferred |
| 4  | sold        |
| 4  | transferred |
+----+-------------+
```

I am currently trying to select all entries from `entities` where "sold", "bought", and "transferred" exist at least once in the `published` table.

Using a left join just pushes a row to the results for every line that exists in published table since an entity can have duplicate published statuses.

So here's what I came up with, and it's working...

```
select
    entities.id,
    (
        select count(distinct `status`)
        from published
        where id = entities.id
            and `status` in ('sold', 'bought', 'transferred')
    ) as statusCount
from entities
having statusCount = 3;
```

This feels kind of clunky. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Either sold, transferred or bought should exist, or all three should exist at least once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the above answer is right.except if you have some other status other than the three mentioned here. You can use the where clause to filter it.

```
SELECT e.Id
FROM entities e INNER JOIN published P
ON e.Id = P.Id
WHERE status in ('sold','bought','transferred')
GROUP BY e.Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Status) >= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e.ID
FROM  entities e INNER JOIN published P
ON e.id = P.id
GROUP BY e.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Status) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Kartik and M. Ali both answer your questions directly - but have you thought of building out your entities table to have flags for each of the states? That would clean things up substantially.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- If we need the entity where 'bought', 'sold' and 'transferred' all appear atleast once
SELECT DISTINCT e.id, e.name
FROM  #published p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #entity e ON e.id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, e.id, e.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE p.status WHEN 'sold' THEN 1 ELSE NULL end) > 0
    AND COUNT(CASE p.status WHEN 'bought' THEN 1 ELSE NULL end ) > 0
    AND COUNT(CASE p.status WHEN 'transferred' THEN 1 ELSE NULL end) > 0

-- If we need the entity where either 'bought', 'sold' or 'transferred' appears atleast once
SELECT DISTINCT e.id, e.name
FROM  #published p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #entity e ON e.id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, e.id, e.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN p.status IN ('sold', 'bought', 'transferred') THEN 1 ELSE NULL end) > 0
```